# PHP Regex in recursion formula

Tags: php, regex

I have a personal expression:

`GREATER (5.26; 7; LESSER (3.00; 6; GREATER (7; 8)))`

I would like a regex a function that would return what contains the parentheses with delimiter for example passing "GREATER" as an expression the regex would return an array with

```
[0] => 5.26; 7
[1] => 7; 8
```

I'm using this regex `preg_match_all("/\((([^()]*|(?R))*)\)/", $valor, $matches);` but it does not return me correctly.

Does anyone have any light on this regex?

Comment: Why do you need recursion ? Just do something like `GREATER\s*\(` add more.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the regex `/(?<=GREATER\s\()([\d.]+)(?:;\s)([\d.]+)/g`.

Breaking this down:

- `(?<=GREATER\s\()` - Does a positive lookbehind on `GREATER (`
- `([\d.]+)` - Grabs any digits and dots that follow this, and groups them
- `(?:;\s)` - Processes but doesn't group the `;` and space
- `([\d.]+)` - Grabs any digits and dots that follow this, and groups them

The global flag (`g`) is required for this to target each of the sets.

Run against the string `GREATER (5.26; 7; LESSER (3.00; 6; GREATER (7; 8)))`

This gives:

```
array(3
    0 => array(2
        0 => 5.26; 7
        1 => 7; 8
    )
    1 => array(2
        0 => 5.26
        1 => 7
    )
    2 => array(2
        0 => 7
        1 => 8
    )
)
```

This allows you access to the 'combined' two sets that proceed the word `GREATER` in the first grouping, in addition to separating the sets out in the subsequent groupings (allowing for easy access).

This can be seen working at PHPLiveRegex **[here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ouY)**.

Comment: `The global flag (g) allows this to work recursively.` No, not recursion in the _regex_ sense.

Comment: Fixed, as I can see that 'applying more than once' and 'recursion' are slightly different things.